# php hacer una web con login y navegar dentro sin perder el logeo de la web

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, mysqli

Hola chic@s tengo este script:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
include_once "conexion.php"; 

function verificar_login($user,$password,&$result) { 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$user' and password = '$password'";
    $rec = mysql_query($sql); 
    $count = 0; 

    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rec)) 
    { 
        $count++; 
        $result = $row; 
    } 

    if($count == 1) 
    { 
        return 1; 
    } 

    else 
    { 
        return 0; 
    } 
} 

if(!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) 
{ 
    if(isset($_POST['login'])) 
    { 
        if(verificar_login($_POST['user'],$_POST['password'],$result) == 1) 
        { 
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $result->idusuario; 
            header("location:index.php"); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            echo '<div class="error">Su usuario es incorrecto, intente nuevamente.</div>'; 
        } 
    } 
?> 

<style type="text/css"> 
*{ 
    font-size: 14px; 
} 
body{ 
background:#aaa; 
} 
form.login { 
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F1F1F1; 
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD; 
    font-family: sans-serif; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 278px; 
    box-shadow:0px 0px 20px black; 
    border-radius:10px; 
} 
form.login div { 
    margin-bottom: 15px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
} 
form.login div label { 
    display: block; 
    float: left; 
    line-height: 25px; 
} 
form.login div input[type="text"], form.login div input[type="password"] { 
    border: 1px solid #DCDCDC; 
    float: right; 
    padding: 4px; 
} 
form.login div input[type="submit"] { 
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #DEDEDE; 
    border: 1px solid #C6C6C6; 
    float: right; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    padding: 4px 20px; 
} 
.error{ 
    color: red; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    margin: 10px; 
    text-align: center; 
} 
</style> 

<form action="" method="post" class="login"> 
    <div><label>Username</label><input name="user" type="text" ></div> 
    <div><label>Password</label><input name="password" type="password"></div> 
    <div><input name="login" type="submit" value="login"></div> 
</form> 
<?php 
} else { 
    echo 'Su usuario ingreso correctamente.'; 
    echo '<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>'; 
} 
?>
```

Este es el archico php llamado conexion:

```
<?php 
// datos para la coneccion a mysql 
define('DB_SERVER','localhost'); 
define('DB_NAME','shaiyar1_almacen'); 
define('DB_USER','root'); 
define('DB_PASS','Admin456'); 

$con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS); 
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con); 
?>
```

este el de salida del sistema llamado logout.php

```
<?php 
    session_start(); 
    session_destroy(); 

    header('location: index.php'); 
?>
```

la consulta seria para my SQL asi:

```
CREATE TABLE `usuarios` ( 
  `idusuario` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `usuario` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
  `password` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY  (`idusuario`) 
)
```

Algo a lo que yo le llamo en lo personal me personan la ignorancia, "Entrelazado" no se como se llama en realida a mi pregunta  o problematica que hare a continuacion:

Quiero hacer algo como una web con sistema de logeo el scrip de arriba me viene exelente lo que no de es que ¿Como hago para enlazar ese index? con otro php ejemplo compra.php que en el link en vez de salirme

```
www.miweb.com`
```

quiero que me salga asi y no se hacerlo osea estoy crudo:

```
www.miweb.com/compra-login=idusuario
```

osea el idusuario sea lo que identifique y pueda crear varias webs

yo he creado web básicas tales como

```
www.miweb.com/index.php
```

cuando voy a la siguiente web

lo hago así

```
www.miweb.com/compra.php
```

**NOTA: yo se hacer consultas PHP mssql y mysql para iniciar secciones lo que no se es el "entrelazado", si la respuesta no la pueden publicar me sirve de mucho para poder investigar el nombre real de "entrelazados"**

Comment: si te refieres a que según los parámetros dados por el usuario, la respuesta del script sea llevarte a otra página, eso se llama redirección

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tu quieres hacer se llama reescritura de url, pero aparte de ello necesitas modificar los links a los que apuntas, por ejemplo si estas usando la variable de session, cuando cargues la página por ejemplo imprimes una etiqueta de anchor con esa variable de session

```
<a href="/compra-login=<?= $_SESSION['userid'] ?>"> Compra </a>
```

con esto asocias la página por medio de un link usando el id del usuario.

Y como te comentaba al principio necesitas reescritura de url, para ello si usas apache ejecuta `a2enmod rewrite` si estás en linux, si usas windows creo que ya Xamp o wamp lo traen por defecto, y en tu carpeta donde tienes el proyecto creas un archivo llamado `.httaccess` en cual agregarás el código para humanizar esas url, puedes seguir el ejemplo que muestran acá http://www.emenia.es/como-crear-urls-amigables-con-htaccess/ por que tambien dependerá de la forma en que quieras reescribir

Answer (score 0):

Después del login usa el header `location`:

```
header("location:/compra-login=idusuario");
```

O después del logout:

```
header("location:/compra-login=idusuario");
```